# JavaFX source code not showing

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I downloaded the JavaFx source code from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/summary.

The name of the folder in the zip file is `re-e71070b0e0c0`.

I unzipped this and added the folder under Project Structure - Global Libraries in Idea, however it doesn't work. When I try to open a class it just shows field names and `/* compiled code */`. I couldn't find anything in the manual.

Comment: If it is intellij, my answer may help you [you can easily solve this problem without downloading Javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74766391/20496704)

Comment: If it is intellij, my answer may help you "[you can easily solve this problem without downloading Javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74766391/20496704)"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Much of the information in this answer is now outdated.

More up-to-date information on using JavaFX with Java 11+ in IntelliJ Idea, is available at:

- [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) in the section titled: "JavaFX and IntelliJ".

Though, the above-linked article is more focused on using JavaFX in IntelliJ rather than viewing JavaFX library source code in IntelliJ.

---

*These instructions are only necessary for the JavaFX 2.x branch and will be obsoleted once JDK 8 is released.*

After you have downloaded the source zip and extracted it, open Idea and follow these instructions:

1. Modify the source structure for your 1.7 SDK:

   `File | Project Structure | SDKs | Sourcepath`

For each sub-project in the extracted zip, type `Alt+Insert` and add the respective source directory.  For example `rt-e71070b0e0c0\javafx-ui-charts\src`, `rt-e71070b0e0c0\javafx-ui-common\src`, etc.  Not all JavaFX 2.x source code is currently open sourced, so this will only add the open sourced portions.

2. Set the documentation lookup path:

   `File | Project Structure | SDKs | Documentation Paths`

Specify a url <kbd>Alt+S</kbd> for the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/

3. In your JavaFX application source, place your cursor over a JavaFX class usage, for instance LineChart:
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> to open the source code file LineChart.java from your downloaded zip.
5. Press <kbd>Shift+F1</kbd> to open documentation on the LineChart in a browser.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> to get quick access to documentation from in the IDE.

**Update Oct 16 2013**

[JDK 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) now includes JavaFX source files.

To tell Idea where JavaFX sources are:

1. Modify the source structure for your 1.8 SDK:

   `File | Project Structure | SDKs | Sourcepath`

Press <kbd>Alt+S</kbd> to add the file `javafx-src.zip`, which is located in the root directory of the JDK 8 distribution.

2. Set the documentation lookup path:

   `File | Project Structure | SDKs | Documentation Paths`

Specify a url <kbd>Alt+S</kbd> for the documentation: http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs.

The JDK 8 JavaFX documentation url will likely change when JDK 8 reaches General Availability release stage.

Step 3 above provides keyboard shortcuts to quickly access the JavaFX sources and documentation from your project.

Answer (score 4):

*(Since this is one of the Google hits for "javafx source code", I'll dump this anwer here too):*

Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13553814/39334): For Java 8, **the source of the public parts of JavaFX are actually laying right along in the JDK installation as a sibling of *src.zip*: *javafx-src.zip*** - on the root of your normal JDK Java 8 installation.

Eclipse doesn't by default link them up when you add the JRE (or it finds it itself) - obviously a bug - so you'll have to do that yourself, by hitting *Preferences* -> *Installed JREs*. Find your *JDK 8*, hit *Edit* button. On the list *JRE system libraries*, expand the *jfxrt.jar* node, and link in the *javafx-src.zip* file.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this problem on Ubuntu 16.04 with JavaFX 8 (`open-jfx` package). The fix was to install the missing source package:

```
sudo apt install openjfx-source
```

IntellJ started showing JavaFX source code the second after the command finished executing.