# JavaFX - can't link controller with data array

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm writing an music player and I can't link my Observable Array with TableView defined in controller. When project runned, I get NullPointerException on line under comment. I don't know what is making it happen and how find way around this problem.

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    ObservableList<CModel> modelData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

            SplitPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Player.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            PlayerController controller = loader.getController();

            //this line gives exception
            controller.setData(this);

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ObservableList<CModel> getPersonData() {
        return modelData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**PlayerController.java**

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class PlayerController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<CModel> cTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CModel, String> artCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CModel, String> albCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CModel, String> trNameCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CModel, String> trNoCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CModel, String> durCol;

    @FXML
    private Menu addFile;

    @FXML
    private Menu addFolder;

    @FXML
    private Menu savePlayL;

    @FXML
    private Menu loadPlayL;


    private Files files;



    private Main main;

    public PlayerController() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        artCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<CModel,String>("artistName")
            );

        albCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<CModel,String>("albumName")
            );

        trNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<CModel,String>("trackName")
            );

        trNoCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<CModel,String>("trackDurationName")
            );

        durCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<CModel,String>("trackNumberName")
            );



    }


    @FXML 
    protected void handleAddFile(ActionEvent event) {
        files = new Files();
        files.openFile();
    }

   public void setData(Main mainApp) {
        this.main = mainApp;

        cTable.setItems(main.getPersonData());
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `loader.load()` method of instantiated object, instead of using static method, before getting controller, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402736/controller-returning-null-in-javafx-helloworld) for details.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to be considered here. In order to get the controller, you need to remember the following things :

- Use the `FXMLoader` reference to load the FXML
- Call the non-static `load` method. Inorder to do that pass a `InputStream` as a parameter.

Inside your `Main.Java`, you should have :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
SplitPane root = (SplitPane)loader.load(getClass().getResource("Player.fxml").openStream());
```

If you don't want to use `InputStream`, you can also pass the resource in the constructor and call the non-staic `load()` method

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Player.fxml"));
SplitPane root = (SplitPane)loader.load();
```

Comment: I did what you wrote and it didin't help. Still I'm getting null exception

Comment: I missed the openStream, please check it again. If we don't use `InputStream` as a parameter, it will still reference the static method

Comment: Now it works! Thanks, Suprised that I couldn't find it in Oracle tutorials, it is quite important aspect of griping on javafx.

Comment: Yeah, true. This is somehow missing in the documents