# Removing JavaFX Scroll Pane Hotkeys

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

I'm trying to put a text box (custom rendered) into a ScrollPane except when I hit space to put a space into the text box, space is also the hotkey to scroll down in the scroll pane so it enters the space and than scrolls down in the scroll pane. How do i remove the hotkey that space scrolls down in the ScrollPane? I've been searching through ScrollPane looking for anything relating to vertical scroll bar or hotkey but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

See this link
[JavaFX: scrolling vs. focus traversal with arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625218/javafx-scrolling-vs-focus-traversal-with-arrow-keys)
i think it's what you want ,try to change `switch-case` method with something like this

```
switch (event.getCode()) {
Case SPACE:
...
}
```