# How to get Source jar files for JavaFX classes?

Tags: jakarta-ee, javafx-2

I have setup JavaFX Project in eclipse, now I want to see proper code with javadocs for certain classes in javafx. Where to download that source jar for this platform ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDK8 ships with javafx-src.zip in it's root directory.

For more detail see the related answer to [JavaFX source code not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407017/javafx-source-code-not-showing-in-intellij-idea).

I don't use Eclipse, but I'm guessing if you use Java 8 with a recent version of [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html), it will include simple keystoke navigation to JavaFX docs and sources from within the editor.  If not, you could add a feature request for this against the e(fx)clipse project and in the meantime configure your JavaFX Eclipse projects manually to be aware of JavaFX docs and source (like you can currently do in Idea).

Comment: This is correct e(fx)clipse nightly know about this location. See http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/10/17/efxclipse-nightly-and-jdk8b111/

Comment: But jdk 8 is still in beta version I guess, don't we have source jar for javafx in java7_update45 ?

Comment: @dhroove no, JavaFX for Java 7 is mostly closed source, only JavaFX for Java 8 is completely open source.

Comment: jewelsea is right most parts of FX2 are closed source. the part that is opensourced is available in the mercurial repo, you could clone it, export it as a zip-file and attach it to your classpath