# Javafx javadocs in intellij does not work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-8

i am trying to write some JavaFX code in Intellij community edition, and i have problem with JavaFX javadocs, see picture below:

[Intellij JavaFx javadoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19luL.png)

It is same with JavaFX project or Maven project. In Netbeans JavaFX javadocs works fine out of the box.

Comment: I know this question was asked 2 years ago. Since you still seem to be an active member, I was thinking it may be helpful to post your operating system at the time as well.

Comment: See #2 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409072/1159643

Answer (score 0):

Through the following few steps, you can easily solve this problem without downloading Javadoc

First : Go to "openjfx.io" to download the Java FX applicable to your device(Just download the SDK)

[Download the SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHlbm.png)

Second : Find the file you just downloaded in your device (should be a zip file), unzip it, Open the decompressed file, you will find a javafx-sdk-19 folder (depending on the version you downloaded, there will be a different number at the end), I usually rename the folder to Java FX (Although I named it JFX ), Then you can move this folder to whatever file path you want it to be in, Be sure to remember the new path to the folder

[new path to folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFjQN.png)

Second : Open IntelliJ, Find Project Structure as shown in the figure below, and click it

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Kk1.png)

Fifth : Click Global Libraries, then click "+"

[click "+"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cedNM.png)

Sixth : Select Java, and select the "lib" folder in the folder where Java FX is located, then click "OK", continue to click "OK"

[select the lib folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15hiq.png)

[continue to click OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zx5K.png)

Seventh : Click add and select "src.zip" under the Java FX folder, click "OK", continue to click "OK"

[select "src.zip"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiTPC.png)

Eighth : Click on "Modules", then select "Dependencies", then click "+", then click "Library...", "Choose lib" under "Global Libraries", Click “Add Selected”, Click "Apply", then click "OK"

[click "Library..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w10Rw.png)

Complete the above steps to use the Javadoc of Java FX